# Does Scala IDE has *.sbt syntax highlighting support?

Tags: scala, playframework, ide

I'm using Scala Ide 4.0.0-rc3 and for a new Play Framework application, I can't seem to get syntax highlighting enabled for *.sbt files. Do we have support for it in Eclipse yet?

[image: Syntax Highlighting missing for *.sbt in Scala Ide]

Comment: No idea - I get `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit cannot be cast to org.scalaide.core.internal.jdt.model.ScalaCompilationUnit` if I try changing *.sbt file association to scala editor and scala script editor seems to have no syntax highlighting

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned by [@Mirko Stocker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/313873/mirko-stocker), this isn't currently supported. However, I've found that associating `*.sbt` with the JavaScript Editor produces decent highlighting

## Configuration

Open *Preferences* and configure:

[image]

## Result

The following shows an example `sbt` file after making the configuration above:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, this hasn't been implemented yet. There's a project to [provide better sbt integration into Eclipse](https://github.com/scala-ide/sbt-integration), but it's mainly focused on building and importing projects. If you're using a .scala Build definition, then that's [supported by sbteclipse](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse/wiki/Using-sbteclipse#eclipse-support-for-build-definition).